# JPA JoinTable with two columns referencing to same column in parent table

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g

I am creating entity classes from database (Oracle 11g) in a Java SE 7 application using Netbeans 7.4 RC2. The structure of the tables is defined as below:

[image: Table Structure]

The behind the such a cascade definition is to restrict the user from deleting a code if its defined as parent code. But its just a child code then a user can delete it. Furthermore, a CODE_ID can have 0 to 1 parent codes. As you can see the highlighted column doesn't have a parent defined in the CODE_RELATION table.

When I generate the entity classes from the database using the wizard the classes are generated like below:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "CODES") 
public class Codes implements Serializable {    
    @Id    
    @Column(name = "CODE_ID", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String codeId;    
    @Column(name = "CODE_DESC", length = 200)
    private String codeDesc;        
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE", nullable = false)
    private char active;    
    @JoinTable(name = "CODE_RELATION", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_ID", referencedColumnName = "CODE_ID", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_CODE_ID", referencedColumnName = "CODE_ID", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Codes> codesList;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "codesList")
    private List<Codes> codesList1;   

//Getter, Setter properties
}
```

It seems to me a little bit confusing as I can't see the Cascade constraint referenced anywhere in the generated entity. Does this entity exactly reflects my table structure and constraints?

Any suggestions to improve the structure please.

P.S. I am new to java world.

Comment: Yes, this models your database. CodeList represents the list of parents while codeList1 represents a list of a parent's children.  Deleting a child will cause JPA to remove entries from the join table for the child->parent relations, while removing a parent won't, and so get a constraint error from the database.  If a code can only have one parent, then the code_relation table should be using code_id as the pk to ensure it is unique, or the parent_id could be stored in the codes table

Comment: @Chris : Aaaaah! I was thinking the other way round. I thought codeList1 represents a child's parent. Well, I should test it practically to make sure its doing the right job.